# Clear or add items to a list box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I'm rather new to C# so trying to learn how to do different things in c# using visual studio and i need some help

i have a `CheckListBox` that contains both Deliveries and Pickups when items are selected in the `CheckListBox` it moves them to a `ListBox` when i press a button

however i want it to add only deliveries or only pickups to the `ListBox`, if both a pickup and a delivery is checked and i try to move them i want it to give some kinda or error message like

can't display Both Deliveries & Pickups at the same time

also when i press the button to move them i want it to clear the `ListBox` if it contains any items then add the items that have been checked in the `CheckListBox`

I'm not sure how to do this, what would be the simplest way to go about it?

if could give some example code it would be great

Comment: How are you loading the data? is it from a database or a file? etc

Comment: Have a look at [How to: Add and Clear Items in a ListBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228375(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: How are you descriminating between a Pickup and a Delivery in your CheckListBox, in short what is unique to each type

Comment: @StuartBlackler i have a forum with `TextBoxes` that i enter data into then adds all the data i have put into the `TextBoxes` to the `CheckListBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourListBox.Items.Add();
```

and

```
if (YourListBox.Items.Count != 0)
{    
YourListBox.Items.Clear();
}
```

should do the job.

Comment: i get a red line under `if (YourListBox.Items == 0)` and gives the error operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection' and 'int'

Comment: It should be `if (YourListBox.Items.Count != 0)`.

Comment: @SidHolland thanks that worked

now i just need to get it to give a error message if it tries to move both delivers and Pickups

Comment: @Michael What is it that is different in your `CheckedListBox` between a delivery and a pickup?

Comment: @SidHolland Delivery will have be showen in the `CheckListBox` like
`Delivery(customer name) (customer address) (arrival time)` so it would look a bit like 'Delivery Michael 1 Middle NoWhere 18:00`
where pickups will be `Pickup (delivery name) (delivery address)` which would look like
`Pickup Sid 2 Some Where`

though i think about just adding another `ListBox` that way ill have the delivers shown in 1 `ListBox` and pickups in a different `ListBox`

Comment: @Michael Yes, that would be one way to go. It might be easier than verifying the items selected to see whether there are deliveries and pickups mixed in together and then popping an error message. Probably a better user experience as well.

Comment: @SidHolland yeah think that the way i will go instead making things to difficult for myself specially when Ive just started learning C#
thanks for all your help